# How to alter resolution to portrait mode values with opencv-python?

Tags: python, opencv, portrait

I want to change the video resolution from landscape to portrait mode for output from my inbuilt webcam on the laptop (cv2.VideoCapture(0)). I tried rescaling the frames to get it to work, it does go to portrait mode ( height bigger than width) but the video is skewed/stretched. Is there a way around this ? please help. I am using opencv with python.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. What you want to achieve depends on the webcam you use. The Resolution you want need to be supported by your cam. [this](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/open-cv-python-change-video-resolution-or-scale) small tutorial explains it very good.

If your camera does not support the Resolution you want, you have two possibilites:

1. You Crop the Image to the Resolution you want.
2. If your max resolution does not allow your resolution you can crop it to the biggest resultion possible with your wanted ratio and after that upscale it.

Careful with upscaling. You have different interpolation methods available.